# How to merge two instance of a Model like hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can merge two hashes like this:

```
array = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, {a:3, b:1, d:5}]
array[0].merge(array[1]) do |k, v1, v2|
  [v1, v2].compact.max
end
```

And I want to merge two `ActiveRecord::Base` instances and create new one.
But `ActiveRecord::Base` class doesn't have `merge` method.

How can I merge two instances of a rails model and create a new instance?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord::Base#attributes` returns a hash.
With these hashes we can merge the values of the rails model instances.